# How i can select specific div from multiple divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something like this, and i need to show every div called "plink" just in the main div of each parent, so i tried to fadeIn ".plink" but its doing the same function for all the divs of "plink"

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.plink').hide();
        $('.project').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).next('.plink').fadeIn(400);
        });
        $('.project').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).next('.plink').fadeOut(200);
        });

    });

</script>

<div class="project">
    <div class="plink">
        <div class="go"></div>
        <div class="goplus"><img src="images/more.png" border="0"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><img src="images/portfolio_pic2.png" border="0" alt="projectname"/></div>
    <div class="title">Test1</div>
</div>
<div class="spacer_project"></div>
<div class="project">
    <div class="plink">
        <div class="go"></div>
        <div class="goplus"><img src="images/more.png" border="0"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><img src="images/portfolio_pic.png" border="0" alt="projectname"/></div>
    <div class="title">test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find()` instead of `next()`...

```
$(this).find('.plink').fadeIn(400);
```

because `this` is your `.project` div then you need to "find" the child elements that you are looking for. Using `next()` means you will get the very next element *if* it matches the selector (i.e. it is check to see if the next `.project` div matches the `.plink` selector)

Comment: @wirey: yeah.. I didn't want to, but I forced myself through the pain barrier ;)

Comment: Nice.. and a muse fan too! +1 :)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, I didn't feel right saying that myself... but I am sitting here just waiting for it to happen :D

Comment: it took 10 minutes to confirm the right answer, Here it is :) !

Answer (score 0):

I would go the FIND route like musefan suggested.  Here is the solution code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bx7YC/

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="plink">
        <div class="go">go</div>
        <div class="goplus">goplus</div>
     </div>
     <div class="pic">pic</div>
     <div class="title">Test1</div>
</div>

<div class="spacer_project"></div>

<div class="project">
    <div class="plink">
        <div class="go">go</div>
        <div class="goplus">goplus</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">pic</div>
    <div class="title">Test2</div>
</div>​

$('.plink').hide();

$('.project').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).find('.plink').fadeIn(400);
});
$('.project').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('.plink').fadeOut(200);
});​
```

I replaced the broken img links with simple text for the jsfiddle.